# Redirect terminal output to tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter

I'm trying to make a very simple GUI for my program(here i have replaced it with the test function). I'm able to run my code via the gui, but the output for the program is being displayed in the terminal. I want the output to be visible in my original window instead.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from test import *
from tkinter import *
import os

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width =550, bg ="#202020") 
canvas.pack()

#frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white");
#frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight = 0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

topFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#202020")
topFrame.place(relwidth=1, relheight = 0.75)

bottomFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#202020")
bottomFrame.place(rely=0.75, relwidth=1, relheight = 0.25)


launch = tk.Button(bottomFrame, text="Launch", bg="white", fg="#202020", font="noah 10 bold", padx=20, command=test)
launch.place(in_=bottomFrame, rely=0.5, relx=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

and here is the other file I'm calling the function from :

```
import os
def test():
    print("Hello World")
    os.system("ping 192.168.0.1 -c 4")
```

Is there any way to capture the output of this function and display it in the *topframe* of my gui in realtime?

Comment: use `tkinter` widgets like `Text` or `Label` to display it - and then `label["text"] = "Hello World"`. Eventually you can assign own class to `sys.stdout` and it can redirect `print()` to `Label` or `Text`.

Comment: if you want to display `ping` then you have to use `subprocess` (ie, `subprocess.run()`) instead of `os.system()` to catch displayed data and next you can put it in `Label` or `Text`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163329/redirecting-stdout-to-tkinter-immediately-without-waiting-for-the-process-to-co) may be helpful.

Comment: see also [tkterminal](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkterminal), a Terminal widget for Tkinter

Answer (score 7):

You can create class with function `write()` which insert text to `tkinter.Text` and assign its instance to `sys.stdout` - and then `print()` will send to `tkinter.Text`

```
class Redirect():
    
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self, text):
        self.widget.insert('end', text)
        #self.widget.see('end') # autoscroll

    # some widget may need it
    #def flush(self):
    #    pass
```

and

```
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

# keep original stdout
old_stdout = sys.stdout    

# assing Redirect with widget Text 
sys.stdout = Redirect(text)

root.mainloop()

# assign back original stdout (if you need it)
sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

But `os.system` you will have to replace with ie. `subprocess.run()` to catch output and `print()` it.

```
def test():
    print("Hello World")
    p = subprocess.run("ping -c 4 stackoverflow.com", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(p.stdout.decode())
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import sys
import subprocess

# --- functions ---

def test():
    print("Hello World")
    p = subprocess.run("ping -c 4 stackoverflow.com", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(p.stdout.decode())
    
# --- classes ---

class Redirect():
    
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self, text):
        self.widget.insert('end', text)
        #self.widget.see('end') # autoscroll

    #def flush(self):
    #    pass
    
# --- main ---    
   
root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='TEST', command=test)
button.pack()

old_stdout = sys.stdout    
sys.stdout = Redirect(text)

root.mainloop()

sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

---

Two problems:

It sends text from `subprocess` to widget `Text` after getting all text from `ping`. It may need more work to display line by line.

`test()` needs some time to finish work and it blocks `tkinter` so it can't update widgets and it freezes. It may need to run `test()` in separated `thread` but I don't know if this will not gives other problems because in many GUI frameworks you can't use widgets in separated threat.

---

**EDIT:**

Version with `threading`. It resolvs previous problems.

But it may have new problems :)

- you can click button two times and it will run two `pings` at the same time and mix strings from both `pings`
- code doesn't have method to stop thread (ie. when you run `ping` without `-c 4`)

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import subprocess
import threading 

# --- functions ---

def run():
    threading.Thread(target=test).start()

def test():
    print("Hello World")

    p = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 4 stackoverflow.com".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        msg = p.stdout.readline().strip() # read a line from the process output
        if msg:
            print(msg)

    print("Finished")
             
# --- classes ---

class Redirect():

    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self, text):
        self.widget.insert('end', text)
        #self.widget.see('end') # autoscroll

    #def flush(self):
    #    pass

# --- main ---    

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='TEST', command=run)
button.pack()

old_stdout = sys.stdout    
sys.stdout = Redirect(text)

root.mainloop()

sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

---

**EDIT: 2021.08.19**

Version with `Scrollbar` and `autoscroll`

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import subprocess
import threading 

# --- classes ---

class Redirect():

    def __init__(self, widget, autoscroll=True):
        self.widget = widget
        self.autoscroll = autoscroll

    def write(self, text):
        self.widget.insert('end', text)
        if self.autoscroll:
            self.widget.see("end")  # autoscroll
        
    #def flush(self):
    #    pass

# --- functions ---

def run():
    threading.Thread(target=test).start()

def test():
    print("Thread: start")

    p = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 4 stackoverflow.com".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        msg = p.stdout.readline().strip() # read a line from the process output
        if msg:
            print(msg)

    print("Thread: end")

# --- main ---    

root = tk.Tk()

# - Frame with Text and Scrollbar -

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

text = tk.Text(frame)
text.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

text['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
scrollbar['command'] = text.yview

old_stdout = sys.stdout    
sys.stdout = Redirect(text)

# - rest -

button = tk.Button(root, text='TEST', command=run)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()

# - after close window -

sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, this definitely addresses my issue, although not to the fullest, as you mentioned, it freezes the app and when the wait time is longer wont be viable, ill try to find ways to fix that

Comment: link to [Redirecting stdout to tkinter immediately (without waiting for the process to complete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163329/redirecting-stdout-to-tkinter-immediately-without-waiting-for-the-process-to-co) in @acw1668 comment seems useful to resolve this problem

Comment: hi @furas I am using your first approach but self.widget.insert('end', text) doesn't implement autoscroll have to add self.widget.see("end") beneath it. Any idea why ? could be my code is slighty different from yours ?

Comment: actually I tested your first snippet too it seems doesbt autoscroll to bottom either

Comment: @pippo1980 my code doesn't use `self.widget.see("end")` but it should be in `write()`. I added it in answer. Did you run exactly my code to test if it works with your system?

Comment: Yep , it does autoscroll now

Comment: gettingg the AttributeError: 'Redirect' object has no attribute 'flush' too

Comment: My test is different

Comment: if your code needs `flush` then uncomment `def flush(self): pass`

Comment: any chance to redirect shell error too ?? if I use your way and p = subprocess.run(aa ...) where aa = uuuuu I get '/bin/sh: 1: uuuuu: not found' in console and not in my text.widget ?

Comment: got it added stderr=subprocess.STDOUT to  subprocess.run(aa ...) so  subprocess.run(aa ..., stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)